# $H_n(M; A)$ is trivial if $M$ is connected and non-compact

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, compactness, orientation

I have some trouble with a problem set. It is specifically part (i) that I am stuck on (I have left in part (ii) for context):

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold and let $A$ be an abelian group. For a point
> $x \in M$, we write $\rho_x : H_n(M; A) → H_n(M|x; A) = H_n(M, M \setminus \{x\}; A)$ for the canonical map
> from the long exact sequence of the pair $(M, M 
> \setminus \{x\})$.

> (i) Let $\mu \in H_n(M; A)$ be a homology class. Show that the subset
> $$\{x \in M | \rho_x (\mu) =0\}$$
> is both open and closed.

> (ii) Show that $H_n(M; A)$ is trivial if M is connected and non-compact.

The fact that this subset is both open and closed makes it obvious it must either be empty or $M$. Clearly if $\mu =0$ we have that this set is the whole of $M$. I just have no idea on how to proceed.

This exercise corresponds to a section on $R$-orientations (Poincaré duality was not covered up to this point).

Comment: What book are your reading and, at the point of the exercise, what tools do you have at your disposal? For instance, do you already have the Poincare Duality?

Comment: See e.g. Proposition 3.29 in Hatcher's book.

Comment: Do you have tom Dieck's book? Lemma 16.1.1 should give a solution to (i).